# first value of a loop in c++ different for the others

Tags: c++, matlab

I need to put the first value of a loop = 0, and then use a range to start the loop.

In MatLab this is possible : x = [0 -range:range] (range is a integer)
This will give a value of [0, -range, -range+1, -range+2, .... , range-1, range]

The problem is I need to do this in C++, I tried to do by an array and then put in like the value on the loop without success.

```
//After loading 2 images, put it into matrix values and then trying to compare each one.   

for r=1:bRows
    for c=1:bCols
        rb=r*blockSize;
        cb=c*blockSize;

    %%for each block search in the near position(1.5 block size)
    search=blockSize*1.5;
    for dr= [0 -search:search] //Here's the problem.
        for dc= [0 -search:search]
            %%check if it is inside the image
            if(rb+dr-blockSize+1>0 && rb+dr<=rows && cb+dc-blockSize+1>0 && cb+dc<=cols)

                %compute the error and check if it is lower then the previous or not
                block=I1(rb+dr-blockSize+1:rb+dr,cb+dc-blockSize+1:cb+dc,1);
                TE=sum( sum( abs( block - cell2mat(B2(r,c)) ) ) );
                if(TE<E) 
                    M(r,c,:)=[dr dc]; %store the motion vector
                    Err(r,c,:)=TE;    %store th error 
                    E=TE;
                end

            end

        end
    end
    %reset the error for the next search
     E=255*blockSize^2;
end
```

end

Comment: Be more clear. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Precise your question and provide code which you have tried

Comment: a normal loop is *for(int dc = -search; dc<=search;dc++)* , but I need to start for a value of 0 (dc =0) and then the next value (dc=-range) then (dc = -range+1) and so on...

Comment: You could use a flag to mark the first loop pass, then set the value of x to -range... bool first=true; for(int x=-range; x <= range; ++x) { if (first) x = 0; /* code */ if (first) { x = -range; first=false; } }

Comment: al01 thanks, is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't natively support ranges of the kind you know from MatLab, although [external solutions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) are available, if somewhat of an overkill for your use case. However, C++ allows you to implement them easily (and efficiently) using the primitives provided by the language, such as `for` loops and resizable arrays. For example:

```
// Return a vector consisting of
// {0, -limit, -limit+1, ..., limit-1, limit}.
std::vector<int> build_range0(int limit)
{
  std::vector<int> ret{0};
  for (auto i = -limit; i <= limit; i++)
    ret.push_back(i);
  return ret;
}
```

The resulting vector can be easily used for iteration:

```
for (int dr: build_range0(search)) {
  for (int dc: build_range0(search)) {
    if (rb + dr - blockSize + 1 > 0 && ...)
    ...
  }
}
```

The above of course wastes some space to create a temporary vector, only to throw it away (which I suspect happens in your MatLab example as well). If you want to just iterate over the values, you will need to incorporate the loop such as the one in `build_range0` directly in your function. This has the potential to reduce readability and introduce repetition. To keep the code maintainable, you can abstract the loop into a generic function that accepts a callback with the loop body:

```
// Call fn(0), fn(-limit), fn(-limit+1), ..., fn(limit-1), and fn(limit)
template<typename F>
void for_range0(int limit, F fn) {
  fn(0);
  for (auto i = -limit; i <= limit; i++)
    fn(i);
}
```

The above function can be used to implement iteration by providing the loop body as an anonymous function:

```
for_range0(search, [&](int dr) {
  for_range0(search, [&](int dc) {
    if (rb + dr - blockSize + 1 > 0 && ...)
    ...
  });
});
```

(Note that both anonymous functions capture enclosing variables by reference in order to be able to mutate them.)

Comment: I think your approach is correct, I will tried it to put it in the loop and see what I obtain.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm More accurate in what sense? In my view, explicit initialization, looping, and `push_back` are easier to understand and generalize than the use of `std::iota` on a limited range and relying on `std::vector` constructor to provide the initial 0. More importantly, the code refers to an undefined `uint` type. If `uint` is intended to be `unsigned int`, there is the additional problem that negating it will result in a large unsigned number, casting of which to `int` is UB.

Comment: Yep, you approach is perfect. Thank you so much.  But now I have another question, I will post it in another link.  Thanks again @user4815162342.

Comment: @cabezon667 just to be clear: please don't change your question to add a different problem to it. If you have additional questions, which are not *very* strongly related to your original problem, go ahead and ask a new question.

Comment: @user4815162342, yes, I hurried with uint. A more accurate in terms of rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your comment, you could do something like this

```
for (int i = 0, bool zero = false; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;
    if (zero)
    {
        i = 3;
        zero = false;
    }

}
```

This would start at it 0, then after doing what I want it to do, assign i the value 3, and then continue adding to it each iteration.

Comment: This is not really good: OP wants to jump to a negative number after 0. But then you'd trip the `if` *twice*, eventually leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: oh yea I missed that part. But it would still work if his loop wouldnt go up to 0 again. Otherwise you can just use a boolean. Edit: Fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought:) If I may still nitpick: I think the keyword is `bool`, and you can put it next to `int i=0` to make it very C++-y (I *think*).

Comment: Not sure why I wrote boolean instead of bool, thanks :) I put it next to int i=0, never thought of that.